# Is it okay to use the same footnote with exact same words in two different chapters of a thesis?

Tags: phd, research-process

Can I use the same footnote with exact same words in two different chapters? The ibid. is used in case of a repetition of the footnote exact above. But what if I want to use the same footnote in different chapters.

Comment: Why would you need the exact same footnote? That would suggest duplication in the main body. Perhaps it would be better to reword. (There might be cases where duplicate text is acceptable.)

Comment: It depends what is in the footnote. If it is a standard reference to a book/paper/whatever, there is no way to 'reword' and still stick to the standard of you field.

Comment: @henning I don't think this is a duplicate. The phrase "the exact same words" doesn't sound like it refers to citing something for a second time.

Answer (score 8):

Your question is predicated on the largely false assumption that there are detailed, sentence-level rules about what is and is not accepted in "academic writing".  There are no such rules.  Writing is a creative activity.  Use whatever words, footnotes, and anything else most clearly express your ideas.

If you are writing a thesis, check your institution's rules for theses. But I doubt they will include anything this specific.